# Word count function that counts words in a txt file

Tags: java, hashmap, word-count

I'm very new to java here so please bear with me.

I'm currently trying to create code that does the following:

1. Add code to your `processFile` function that counts the number of times each word appears in the file.
2. Add code to your `processFile` function that loops through your `HashMap` to find the most frequent word. After your loop, the variable added for bonus requirement #1 should contain the value for the most frequent word.

So far I've come up with this and was wondering if anyone could please help me progress further.

```
        Map<String, Integer> freq = new Hashmap<String, Integer>();
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("readwords,txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(fi);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.next().toLowerCase();
        Integer f = freq.get(word);
            if (f == null) {
                freq.put(word,1);
            }
            else { 
                freq.put(word,f+1);
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Before asking a question, please make sure that the `code` you are about to post has no compilation issues.

Comment: Will do thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is close, but you've mixed `String` declaration styles, your generic type is missing a `>` and your variable names are inconsistent. I think you wanted something like,

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
File file = new File("readwords.txt");  
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.next().toLowerCase();
        Integer f = map.get(word);
        if (f == null) {
            map.put(word, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(word, f + 1);
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting the words and for getting most frequently used word you can try this:

```
   public void processFile() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("readwords.txt");
        String mostFreqWord = null;
        Integer highestFreq = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(fi);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String word = input.next().toLowerCase();
            Integer f = freq.get(word) == null ? 1 : freq.get(word) + 1;

            freq.put(word, f);

            if(f > highestFreq) {
                mostFreqWord = word;  // set most frequent word
                highestFreq = f;      // frequency of most frequent word
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Word :" + mostFreqWord
                + " is the most frequent word with frequency:" + highestFreq);
    }
```

Since I have modified the code you already posted, here is the explanation of modification that I did (I assume that you already know what your original code was doing).

Inside loop, below line checks if word `word` has encountered first time in loop, if yes then sets it's frequency as 1 otherwise it increments frequency for that word.

```
Integer f = freq.get(word) == null ? 1 : freq.get(word) + 1;
```

Then it sets latest frequency for the word: `freq.put(word, f);`

Statement `if(f > highestFreq)` checks if the highest frequency is still highest, if not then updates `highestFreq` and `mostFreqWord` words.

Comment: could you please explain to me the syntax from "String mostfreqword  to req.put(word,f)  i don't understand the syntax, i understand implementing the scanner to read through the text.

Thank you for the help !

Comment: I just updated what I have modified in the original code.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, one more question. 

is there another syntax for
Integer f = freq.get(word) == null ? 1 : freq.get(word) + 1;

or is this the only way?

Comment: It's ternary operator, alternate way is to use if-else statement.